# Getting List[Serializable] instead of List[(String,String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My initial RDD looks as follows `RDD[(String, List[(String,String)])]`:

```
(600,List((22,33),(55,88)))
(700,List((12,13),(15,18),(18,88)))
```

I want to append each entry with additional data obtained from Redis cache DB. To do this, I use `Sedis` which is a wrapper of `Jedis` for Scala. This is a fragment of my code:

```
import org.sedis._
import redis.clients.jedis._

val redisPool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379, 2000))

val appended = filtered.map({line => (line._1,
    redisPool.withJedisClient { client =>
    val additionalData: List[String] = Dress.up(client).hvals("member_id:"+line._1)
    line._2.union(additionalData)
    })
})
```

The problem is that `appended` is of the format `RDD[(String, List[Serializable]` instead of `RDD[(String, List[(String,String)])]`. What am I doing wrong?
Also, is the way in which I am using `redisPool` inside `map` efficient enough or is there any other better option?

Comment: What is `line._2`s type?

Comment: You say your initial RDD has the type `RDD[(String, List[(String,String)])]`, but the sample data you provided doesn't match that - `(600,List(22,33),List(55,88))` is of type `(String, List[(String, String)], List[(String, String)])`... and the second record is different again. The type inferred by the compiler for the _input_ you provided is `RDD[(Product with Serializable)]`

Comment: @TzachZohar: Sorry, my fault. It is indeed `List((22,33),(55,88))`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: line._2s type is `List[(String,String])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `line._2.union(additionalData)` creates a union of `line._2` which has the type `List[(String, String)]` and of `additionalData` which has the type `List[Sting]`. The result must be the most accurate common type of these two different types - which is `List[Serializable]`.
   If `additionalData` had the type `List[(String, String)]`, that would have been the result type.
2. As for efficiency of JedisPool usage: **usually, when opening connection to some external resource from a Spark transformation, you should use `mapPartitions`**, which executes the given function on each of the RDD's partitions. Why? Under your current implementation, the pool is created on the driver application, then serialized and shipped to each executor, to be deserialized and used in the mapping. This usually **fails**, because such a pool holds some kind of connection (open socket maybe) that doesn't exist on the executors, only on the driver where it was created. One (inefficient) alternative would be to create the pool inside the map function (per record). The better option is to use mapPartitions:

   ```
   val appended = filtered.mapPartitions(iter => {
     val redisPool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "jedis-host", 6379, 2000))

     iter.map({line => (line._1,
       redisPool.withJedisClient { client =>
       val additionalData: List[String] = Dress.up(client).hvals("member_id:"+line._1)
       line._2.union(additionalData)
       })
     })
     // close the pool, if relevant
   })
   ```

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that `List[Serializable]` will actually look like e.g. List((12,33),(12,55),(aa,bb,cc))`, where `(aa,bb,cc)` is the additional data?

Comment: Almost: `List((12,33),(12,55), aa, bb, cc)`

Comment: How can I get an access to each element of this List? I mean how can I get e.g. `aa`? As far as I see `entry(2)` does not work.

Comment: If the list is called `list`, `list(2)` gives you the third element. But I strongly advise against using such a poorly-typed list, the result of `list(2)` would be of type `Serializable` which isn't very useful.